# how to populate a field with parent field data

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to create a record on a BILLING object every time when the bill checked box is checked on another TEST object.

My problem is that there is a required field On the BILLING record called rate__c.
The rate__c field must be populated with the field from PROJECT, which is the parent TEST object.(there is a lookup relationship between test and project. And lookup relationship between billing and project).

I wrote a code that only works when I prefilled the rate__c field in the BILLING record.

I also wrote code that retrieves the rate__c field from the PROJECT object, but for some reason, I get an error message a required field - rate__c is missing.

Please help me solve this problem.

HERE IS MY CODE

```
public class testBillingLineCreate {
    public static void createBillingLine (list<TEST__c> TestList, map<id, TEST__c> oldMap) {
        list<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c> billingLineList=new List<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c>();      
        for(TEST__c objtest:TestList) {
            if(objtest.Billed__c==true && oldMap.get(objtest.Id).Billed__c==false) {
                AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c bill=new AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c();
                bill.AcctSeed__Billing__c=objtest.Billing__c;
                bill.AcctSeed__Project__c=objtest.Project__c;
                bill.AcctSeed__Hours_Units__c=objtest.time__c;                  
                bill.AcctSeed__Rate__c= objtest.Project__r.Billing_Rate__c;
                billingLineList.add(bill);
            }
        }
        insert billingLineList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually handle the error and report it to the child if an error occurs.

Also, related records are not automatically populated in a trigger, so you must query for them first.

```
public class testBillingLineCreate {
    public static void createBillingLine (list<TEST__c> TestList, map<id, TEST__c> oldMap) {
        list<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c> billingLineList=new List<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c>();
        List<Test__c> source = new List<Test__c>();
        Map<Id, Project__c> projects = new Map<Id, Project__c>();
        for(TEST__c objtest:TestList) {
            if(objtest.Billed__c && !oldMap.get(objtest.Id).Billed__c) {
                source.add(objtest);
                projects.put(objtest.Project__c, null);
            }
        }
        projects.putAll([
            SELECT Billing_Rate__c
            FROM Project__c
            WHERE Id = :projects.keySet()
        ]);
        for(TEST__c objtest:source) {
            AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c bill=new AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c();
            bill.AcctSeed__Billing__c=objtest.Billing__c;
            bill.AcctSeed__Project__c=objtest.Project__c;
            bill.AcctSeed__Hours_Units__c=objtest.time__c;                  
            bill.AcctSeed__Rate__c= projects.get(objtest.Project__c).Billing_Rate__c;
            billingLineList.add(bill);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(billingLineList, false);
        for(Integer i = 0, s = results.size(); i < s; i++) {
            if(!results[i].isSuccess()) {
                source[i].addError(results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the user will be advised that they need to populate the rate field. This is also future proof, as you can add more required fields, validation rules, etc, and the user will get an error message.

Comment: Note: I made some assumptions about object names, you'll need to adjust appropriately.